# font-face in IE only working locally

Tags: internet-explorer, font-face

I´ve made the fonts and embedding stuff via fontsquirrel.
In Chrome and Firefox everything works fine.
But in IE it works when I open the html locally, but when I upload it to a server or run it in a local server the font is not being loaded.

Please check this url to see if it works for you. I only see Times New Roman in IE 11:
http://wdgts.com/fonttest/

Maybe it is some strange setting I have in IE?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Your fonts appear correctly in my Internet Explorer 11. If your compatibility mode is turned on, turn it off. Add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` to your `<head>` in the HTML.